# Pre-position an item in Masonry (e.g., 2nd row and 3rd column should always be X)

Tags: jquery-masonry, masonry

Is there is a way to specify where an item should end up on a Masonry layout?

I don't mean in terms of absolute position (as you would do with `stamp`). I mean in terms of flow, for example: X should always be displayed on the 2nd row of the 3rd column, regardless of its actual absolute position.

I read the documentation but can't find anything to achieve that. If it does not exist, do you have some recommendations on how to go about it?